# Please check if I did correctly for my proof by contrapositive question!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification

Suppose m ∈ ℤ. Prove by contrapositive that if m^2-2m-3 is even, then m is odd.

My working:

```
Suppose m is any even integer.
Hence,   m = 2k
Thus,    m^2-2m-3 = (2k)^2-2(2k)-3
                  = 4k^2-6k-2k-3
                  = 4k^2-4k-3
                  = 2(2k^2-2k)-3
```

I am not sure if I am doing it correctly here. How do I continue to show that m^2-2m-3 is odd? Thankyou.

Comment: It's fine: $-3=-4+1$. Thus $m^2-2m-3 = 2(2k^2-2k)-3 = 2(2k^2-2k)-4+1=2(2k^2-2k-2)+1$

Comment: I think you should state the contrapositive -- if m is even, then m^2-2m-3 is odd.  Then what follows is fine.  As for the last step.  The first term is clearly even and the second term is odd.  The sum of the two must be odd.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format, for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I continue to show that m^2-2m-3 is odd?

By showing that there exists some integer, $h$, where $m^2-2m-3 = 2h+1$.

As the comments have mentioned, you are almost done.   You merely need to expand $-3$ into $-4+1$ to get the required form.

---

We shall prove by contraposition that any integer *$m$ is odd if $m^2-2m-3$ is even*.

Suppose that an arbitrary integer $m$ is *not* odd, aiming to show that $m^2-2m-3$ must *not* be even if this is so.

By the supposition, there exists some integer $k$ where $m=2k$.

By substitution and algebra we derive: $$\begin{align}m^2-2m-3 &= (2k)^2-2(2k)-3\\&= 4k^2-4k-3\\&=4k^2-4k-4+1\\&=2(2k^2-2k-2)+1\end{align}$$

Let $h=(2k^2-2k-2)$.   Because it is a series of products of integers, this $h$ is an integer.

Therefore the supposition *does* entail that there exists some integer $h$, where $(m^2-2m-3)=2h+1$.

So demonstrating that: **$\bf m^2-2m-3$ cannot be even if $\bf m$ is not odd** as we aimed.

Finally, by contraposition we have that: **$\bf m$ is odd if $\bf m^2-2m-3$ is even**, as was to be proven.

$\blacksquare$